# Excel: SUMIF with text resulting in a zero answer

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

```
    Name   Count
     Ball    1
     racket  1
     Ball    1
```

I am using `=SUMIF(A2:A4,"Ball",B2:B4)`
The total produced is `0` instead of `2`.

I have generated this formula for several different "Names" in my spreadsheet and it has yielded the correct answers. I cannot figure out why it won't do it in this instance.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem by placing a space after the word `Ball`. To Excel, the word **"Ball "** does not equal **"Ball"**. Therefore, the sum is `0`. Check to see if there are spaces after the words in the `Name` column.

Answer (score 1):

Excel includes spaces as text characters. So to Excel, the word `"Ball "` does not equal to the word `"Ball"`. If there are spaces at the end of the words, we may not see them, but Excel will see them and treat it as a different word.

Therefore, if you have a space at the end of the text being checked, the sum will be `0`. Check to see if there are spaces after the words in the `Name` column. Removing them should solve the problem.